# Mapping an application in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, client-server, cloud

I have this project that involves both a client and a server. I developped both parts of the application in java and I want to test it in a hadoop cluster, since the server side is a simulation of a cloud, so by using hadoop I want to give my application a real sense of cloud environment. I started by creatin a multi-node Hadoop Cluster but I don"t know what should be the next step.
I would appreciate any enlightening.

Comment: Is Hadoop set up correctly on both clusters already? I'd recommend this link for a step-by-step guide: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Comment: Details? What does the application actually do? Hadoop is for running batch jobs, not for serving client requests.

Comment: yes. what should I do next?

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: the client is outsourcing a file to the server after making some computation over it. The server stores the file, and upon request it computes some result using the file and send it to the client, that finally checks the correctness of these results

Comment: @AndrewMartin I actually followed that tutorial in setting up my clusters. I just wrote the  brief description of both sides

Comment: I don't know that much about Hadoop, but to my knowledge it's for simultaneous processing of files, to increase efficiency. It doesn't sound like you're using if for that purpose.

Comment: My file(which should be considered very heavy : Big Data)  is going to be processed in splits simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to accomplish this would be to use a restful interface to send the commands.

For instance, on the computer that is the JobTracker, you could host a tomcat rest server. (Make sure that the hadoop dameons are running in the background). You could use a Spring/Hibernate based servlet in order to process the requests to the server. Finally, in the servlet, you could either include the hadoop-jars and call hadoop through the hadoop API, or you can call hadoop through the console (./hadoop runjar blah).

In order to upload files to the Server, you can use an sftp interface, or possibly directly upload files to the hdfs.

If you would like, I can share some code with you, because I have done a similar project.

Also, you can look into Apache Oozie. They host a restful job flow api for hadoop.

Comment: Your idea seems like what I am looking for. Yes I would love if you could share with me your previous experience and I will take a look at  this Oozie